# How should I make a string from a lazy sequence in clojure?

Tags: string, printing, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I use str to construct strings all the time:

```
user> (str '(1 2 3) " == " '(1 2 3))
"(1 2 3) == (1 2 3)"
```

and roughly once a day I get bitten on the ass by:

```
user> (str '(1 2 3) " == " (map identity '(1 2 3)))
"(1 2 3) == clojure.lang.LazySeq@7861"
```

I guess I can say:

```
user> (with-out-str (print '(1 2 3) " == " (map identity '(1 2 3))))
"(1 2 3)  ==  (1 2 3)"
```

instead, but it seems ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `print-str`:

```
(print-str '(1 2 3) " == " (map identity '(1 2 3)))
;; => "(1 2 3) == (1 2 3)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a LazySeq object into a Cons one by using `seq`:

```
user=> (str '(1 2 3) " == " (map identity '(1 2 3)))
"(1 2 3) == clojure.lang.LazySeq@7861"

user=> (str '(1 2 3) " == " (seq (map identity '(1 2 3))))
"(1 2 3) == (1 2 3)"
```